# Too many active changes in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When there's a directory with a particularly large amount of files (ex. node_modules), VSCode will complain that there are too many active changes. It's simple enough to add the directory to .gitignore, however, the git tab in VSCode gets stuck loading, and I'm unable to view any relevant changes unless I completely restart VSCode.

Is there a way to refresh the git tab in VSCode without completely restarting the application? The refresh button at the top of the git tab seems to have no effect.

I'm using Microsoft's Remote Development extension if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask VSCode to totaly ignore some files/directories from being displayed/watched from your project.

To do so, at the root of your projects create a `.vscode` folder with a `settings.json` file in it. This file will contains VSCode related configuration proper to this project only.

In this `settings.json`, add:

```py
{
     "files.exclude": {
          "**/node_modules/": true,
          "another_large_folder_to_ignore": true
     },
     "files.watcherExclude": {
          "**/node_modules/": true,
          "another_large_folder_to_ignore": true
     }
}
```

Comment: This seems reasonable. In my testing, I could add a directory to the settings.json, save, and it would no longer appear in searches. Removing the directory and saving would immediately allow it to start appearing in searches again. However, it appears a restart is still required for changes in the git tab to update accordingly, which is a bit unfortunate. It's not too much of a hassle to restart, especially since this situation rarely occurs, I just thought I might be missing some VSCode feature which would make my life easier (which it appears I was!) Thanks for the help.